# The difference between filtering a specific column in 'On Clause ' of a join statement and 'Where clause'

Tags: t-sql, performance, sql-server-2016, optimization, query, query-performance

I have two tables with these structures:

```
Table1(Date ,Code ,Name)
Table2(Date ,Code)
```

I need to filter a specific `date` for both tables. For instance I need data only for '10/28/2019' from each table.I want to know whether there are differences between these two queries in terms of the final result and query performance. In the `First query` I'm filtering `dates` in `ON clause` and in the `second query` I'm filtering `dates` in the `where clause`.
Will there be any condition that these two queries produce different result set?
Thanks in advance.

query1 :

```
      Select "Desired Columns"
      From Table1 T1 Inner Join Table2 T2
      On T1.Date = "The specific date" and
         T2.Date = "The specific date" and
         T1.Code = T2.Code
```

query2:

```
      Select "Desired Columns"
      From Table1 T1 Inner Join Table2 T2
      On T1.Code = T2.Code
      where T1.date ="The specific date" and T2.Date = "The specific date"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will there be any condition that these two queries produce different result set?

Logically, both queries must produce same result set, but deepening on [Query Optimizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#optimizing-select-statements) and [Logical Processing Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) both queries may produce different work-load (CPU Worker time, Logical Reads etc..) due to following condition:

- Query 1:
  Retrieves the **filtered** rows based on `ON` clause `FROM` tables, renders as  per `SELECT` clause
- Query 2:
  Retrieves the rows `FROM` tables, get **filtered** based on `WHERE` clause and renders as per `SELECT` clause

Following query can help to see the stats of the both queries. You could also have IO insights by setting `SET STATISTICS IO ON`

```
SELECT  t.[text] as sql_Text, 
        s.total_elapsed_time, 
        ((s.total_elapsed_time + 0.0) /s.execution_count) as avg_elapsed_time,
        s.total_worker_time, 
        ((s.total_worker_time + 0.0) / s.execution_count) as avg_worker_time,
        s.total_clr_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s 
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.[sql_handle]) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'%From Table1 T1 Inner Join Table2 T2%'
ORDER BY s.last_execution_time;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer .
So based on what you've said , query number one is better in terms of performance. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @PanteaTourang, yes, that is correct, but you must ensure the same looking at stats (as mentioned in answer) since it may vary based on complex expressions in `SELECT` clause

Comment: Hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I mean the first query could be better based on standard query processing order (as the rows get filtered prior to `WHERE` clause filter). Although, actual work-load must be measured from query/IO stats.

Answer (score 3):

Your particular example uses and inner join. The results will always be the same whether you use ON or WHERE.

I think of the ON clause as applying the predicate to the row from the right-hand table *before* it is combined with the left-hand row. The WHERE applies after the combination is formed. This is just how I think inside my head. The query optimizer does not work this way. I'll use an **outer** join to demonstrate what I'm saying.

```
Table1       Table2
------       ------
A            A
B

Query 1:
select * from t1
left outer join t2
  on t2.col = t1.col
where t2.col is null;

Query 2:
select * from t1
left outer join t2
  on t2.col = t1.col
  and t2.col is null;
```

Let's step through Q1. First A is read from t1. Then the ON clause says "find matching rows from t2". This returns A from t2 and we have an output row (A, A). Then we read B from t1. Again the ON says "find matching rows from t2". This time there is no match. Since it's an outer join we return (B, NULL). Now we've read all the rows and we apply the WHERE clause. Only one output row has t2 as NULL so query 1 returns

```
(B, NULL)
```

Repeat with Q2. We read t1 and return A. We read t2 but now the ON says t2's value must by both A and also NULL. No row matches. It's an outer join so we return (A, NULL). We read the next row from t1 getting B. We look in t2 for "B and NULL" and do not get a match. We return (B, NULL). There is no where clause so we're done. Query 2 returns

```
(A, NULL)  
(B, NULL)
```

Different results depending on whether the predicate is in the ON clause or the WHERE clause, but only with outer joins.