# How can Inner join be optimize?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, join

I have a table where there are in some cases twin records.

In the table, I have the following columns:

- id (identity column)
- action_id
- session_id
- row_id
- timestamp
- ...and more records.

I need to find a twin record for a specific `id`.

A twin record for `action_id=11` is when `action_id=12` and `session_id`, `row_id` and `timestamp` are the same.

### Table Defintion

Assuming my table created as follows. (no additional index)

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
      [id]         BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      [session_id] BIGINT   default @@SPID,
      [row_id]     BIGINT   default 0,
      [timestamp]  DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      [action_id] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      [value1]     NVARCHAR(max) NULL, 
      [value2]     NVARCHAR(max) NULL,
      [value3]     NVARCHAR(max) NULL)
```

### Select Statement

My current query is:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM [table_name] d INNER JOIN [table_name] i 
   ON d.[session_id] = i.[session_id] 
   AND d.[row_id] = i.[row_id] 
   AND d.[timestamp] = i.[timestamp] 
WHERE  d.[action_id] = 12 
   AND i.[action_id] = 11 
   AND i.[id] = X -- where X is the input
```

### Questions

I want the query to be as fast as it can, so my questions are:

- Is there a difference if I move the `where` condition in the joins?

  ```
  SELECT d.* 
      FROM [table_name] d INNER JOIN [table_name] i 
         ON d.[session_id] = i.[session_id] 
         AND d.[row_id] = i.[row_id] 
         AND d.[timestamp] = i.[timestamp] 
         AND d.[action_id] = 12 
         AND i.[action_id] = 11 
      WHERE  i.[id] = X -- where X is the input
  ```
- Should I add an index for the `timestamp`, `row_id` and `session_id` columns?
- What will happen first, `JOIN` the tables, or filter results by `WHERE`?
- is the following query is better?

  ```
  SELECT d.* FROM (
     (SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE [id] = X AND action_id = 11) i 
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE [id] > X AND action_id = 12) d
         ON  d.[session_id] = i.[session_id] 
         AND d.[row_id] = i.[row_id] 
         AND d.[timestamp] = i.[timestamp]
   )
  ```
- What else can I do to make it run faster?

Comment: Why did you not add the index, and found out yourself that this would make the query faster?

Comment: You also use `action_id` and `id` in the WHERE clause... Are the indexed? Can you show use the DDL of this table?

Comment: @Luuk id is identity and pk, so it also indexed. the rest of the columns are used only for this query.

Comment: How many records are there in your table? 100'000 or 1'000'000 or only a couple of thousand records? Seeing as the column `id` has been defined as `identity` are you sure it is always `11`, because an `IDENTITY`would be unique. See [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) property (Microsoft | SQL Server Docs).

Comment: Can u please include details asked by hot2use as well as provide the query plan which is having performance issue.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use The table may contain more than 100k records.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a difference if I put the where condition at the join
>   section?

In your case, NO. `Optimizer` is smart enough to understand.

`Where Clause` further put filter on what is produce by JOIN.

`INNER JOIN` :Here `WHERE clause` do not have much to to put filter.It has smaller resultset to apply filter.  In fact, in case of, `INNER JOIN`, it do not matter where you put `condition` in the `JOIN` or `WHERE`. `Optimizer` is smart enough to understand.There is no performance difference .

`OUTER JOIN`: Here `WHERE clause`  have much larger resultset to apply filter.
Since `Where clause` have much larger resultset to filter out, it make sense to `Filter` as much as possible in `JOIN ON` condition,so that smaller resultset is produce.

If where condition is applied in Right table ,then such `LEFT JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`

Though in most cases of `OUTER JOIN`, optimizer is smart enough to understand and convert the `WHERE` to `ON` internally.

It depend upon example to example, specially in `complex query` involving `large volume` of data.It is always wise to check the query plan and decide `WHERE` condition accordingly.

You should use `predicate` column in `ON` ,which logically relate the joining table.

If it is `filter` condition then use it in `Where` clause.

> Should I add an index for the timestamp, row_id, session_id?

Yes. Create `composite Non clustered index`.Choice of `Clustered index([id])` is perfect.

```
Create NonClustered Index NCI_Table_Action_Row_Session_Timestamp 
on table_name(action_id,row_id,session_id,Timestamp)
GO
```

Notice the order of columns. The narrow column should be in LEFT most.
There is no point in `Covering index` as `nvarchar(max)` are not use in `covering index`.

> What else can I do to make it run faster?

I think instead of `INNER` use `EXISTS`.Don't use `*`

```
SELECT d.[id]     ,
      [session_id] ,
      [row_id]     ,
      [timestamp]  ,
      [action_id] ,
      [value1]     , 
      [value2]     ,
      [value3]       
FROM [table_name] d 
where(select 1 from [table_name] i 
   where  i.[id] = X -- where X is the input
  AND i.[action_id] = 11 ---- where 11 is the input
  AND  d.[action_id] = i.[action_id]+1 --12 ---- if 12 is  input then it is more good
  AND d.[session_id] = i.[session_id] 
   AND d.[row_id] = i.[row_id] 
   AND d.[timestamp] = i.[timestamp] 

   )
```

Comment: Whether the predicate is in the JOIN or the WHERE changes the meaning so can affect correctness. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252117/36809).